# How to fix the issues in Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am getting the following error when running an exe which has been created from vb.net and parts of C#.The errors are .

> Error occurred: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException:
>   Failed to save settings: An error occurred executing the configuration
>   section handler for
>   userSettings/Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.UltraToolbarsManager
>   : An error occurred executing the configuration section handler for
>   userSettings/Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.UltraToolbarsManager.
>   ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Shall I need to change the app.config?

Comment: Does this happen every time you save settings?  OutOfMemomryException is generally an indication of a memory leak.  Unless the Infragistics control is the source of the leak, I'd think this failure would be intermittent and the real problem has nothing to do with config.

Comment: yes.it happens when i save the settings

Comment: If this happens every time, you should probably check with Infragistics or on their own forums.  Either the control has an issue or you have a setting that isn't set correctly.  If you want to make sure it's the control, you may need to create a separate simple project to test it out.  You can also download trial versions of a memory profiler to find the source.  However, that will be time consuming.  I'd check with the vendor first.  You may be hitting something that others have hit.